# Main Storyboard Can't be Opened

Tags: xcode

I am trying to build this app for school using the simulator but whenever I try to build it I get this error:

```
The document "MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard" could not be opened. Line 134: XML       
declaration allowed only at the start of the document
```

I go to the Issue navigator but that is all it shows.  There are no errors shown in the code.

Here is the section where line 134 is in the XML source code:

```
    </view>
                    <tabBarItem key="tabBarItem" title="Item 1" id="JGk-R6-tUe"/> //This    
is line 134
                </viewController> 
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="2cL-Ur-7Xa"   
userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
```

Comment: Can you open the storyboard in Xcode? Have you have merge conflicts in this storyboard?

Comment: I am only able to open the Ipad story =board, not the Iphone one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either edit the storyboard file so that Xcode re-saves it or open it in a text editor and see if line 134 needs to be edited or deleted. It sounds like somehow there is a second tag saying that it is an XML file on line 134.

Comment: Thanks.  It turns out that at line 134 the entire chunk of code was copied so deleting it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can right click on the Storyboard file and view it as XML source code.

[image: Open as Source Code]

From there you can go to the offending line, read the XML and make edits that in your best judgement will fix it.